# Opacity not working with QWebEngineView and translucent background

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebengineview

Perhaps this is a bug. There is a top level widget that must have a drop shadow. Inside that widget I want to display a browser (only to be able to render html). The top level widget's opacity must be adjustable.
For the dropshadow to work as expect (not show a black border) we need `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` to be set to true. But then the opacity changing does not work. Why? But what really bothers me is that if you replace the browser widget **with any other widget**, say a `QTextEdit`, the opacity changing works always, including with drop shadow.

I am using Qt5.8 with msvc2015 on Windows 8.1 host.
Here is a working minimal example:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEnginePage>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QGraphicsDropShadowEffect>

class TestWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestWidget(QWidget *parent = 0){
        this->setStyleSheet(".QWidget{color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0 y1:0, x2:1 y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));"
                               "background: qlineargradient( x1:0 y1:0, x2:1 y2:0, stop:0 cyan, stop:1 blue);}");

        QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView;
        view->setUrl( QUrl("https://www.google.de") );
        this->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

        view->page()->setBackgroundColor(QColor(Qt::transparent));

        QWidget *container = new QWidget;
        container->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout );
        container->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
        container->layout()->addWidget( view );
        this->layout()->addWidget( container );

        QSlider *slider = new QSlider;
        slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
        slider->setFixedWidth(200);
        slider->setMinimum(20);
        slider->setValue(20);
        slider->setMaximum(100);
        connect(slider,&QSlider::valueChanged,this,
                [this](int value){
            this->setWindowOpacity(1.0 * value / 100.0);
        });
        slider->show();

        this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,true);
        Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0;
        flags |= Qt::SplashScreen;
        flags |= Qt::FramelessWindowHint;
        setWindowFlags(flags);

        QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *shadow = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
        shadow->setBlurRadius(10);
        shadow->setOffset(0,2);
        shadow->setEnabled(true);
        setGraphicsEffect(shadow);
    }

    ~TestWidget(){}
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

pro file:

```
QT       += core gui webenginewidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = transparent-webpage-over-widget
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the Blink engine even supports transparent windows? I've never seen a browser that had this feature.

Comment: If you remove the window attribute, changing the opacity works, but then you get a black border. but it might still be related to blink...

Comment: I noticed it even does not work if I set a parent to the webview, without adding the webview to a layout.

Comment: If you don't need any interaction with content, you may render a webpage to an image and show it as you want.

Comment: Interaction is the main point, so this is no solution for me. In the meantime I figured out that it works with WebKit. Too bad it has been removed from Qt in favor of Blink, the latter using even more memory, too make things worse. From a user's perspective this was a bad decision. Moreover I noticed that with WebKit, I get clear and crisp fonts for free, which was also a problem I had with blink (see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161662/rendered-text-looks-very-different-in-qt-and-blink-although-same-font-is-set))

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41960, this is now working by simply using this line:

```
webEngineView->page()->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);
```

I've tried it in Qt 5.6 and it works well.

In order to make this answer more helpful, let me show all relevant code.

In MainWindow, I have set this:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setAutoFillBackground(true);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

For the webEngineView object, I have set these attributes:

```
webEngineView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
webEngineView->setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
webEnginePage = webEngineView->page();
// https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41960
webEnginePage->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);
```

In your HTML, use transparent background in your CSS, like this:

`body { background: transparent; }`

otherwise, I think by default the HTML would have a white background

I hope it helps.

Comment: If you really used my code to verify your answer, please update your answer with a working copy **of the complete header file**. Basically I don't see any difference, and it does not work.