# Rendered text looks very different in Qt and Blink, although same font is set

Tags: css, qt, fonts

The upper font is from a `QLabel` with `QFont("Arial")`.
The lower font is rendered with `QWebEngine`, e.g. `Chromium/Blink backend`, using css

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 8pt;
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the blink one look as dark and sharp as the Qt one? It looks blurry and as both texts in the app are placed next to each other, it does not look good enough.

(Qt5.8 msvc 2015 on windows 8.1)

**Edit**

The reason is that chromium since version 52 did drop GDI support. In former version GDI rendering could be activated by disabling the DirectWrite flag. So basically I need to recompile Qt with a different chromium backend. Or perhaps with Cent Browser because it still supports that flag despite using newest chromium.

Answer (score 0):

First get the font family using  `QFontInfo::family()`. 
This function returns matched family name of windows system font.

```
QFont f("Arial");
QFontInfo info(f);
QString family = info.family();
```

In simple terms "**QFontInfo object is used to determine the attributes of the font actually used in the window system.**"

Use the **family name** returned by `QFontInfo` and set the same for `QWebEngine` by `QWebEngineSettings::setFontFamily` or using CSS.

**useful links:**

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontinfo.html#family

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#setFontFamily

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this did not change anything.